# Python Social Address Book

Tags: python

I am having a bit of trouble with this question:

> Consider an address book that, besides addresses, keeps track of
>   someone’s friends. The address book allows to query friends of friends
>   (like LinkedIn does with connections): a friend of degree 1 is a
>   direct friend, a friend of degree 2 is a friend of a friend, etc.
>   There are no friends of degree 0.

How should I start this? Specifically the 'degree' portion.

This is what I have so far:

```
class SocialAddressBook:

def __init__(self):
    """Creates empty address book"""
    self.book = {}

def addName(self, name, address):
    """Adds name to address book, with address and
    no friends"""

def addFriend(self, name, friend):
    """Adds friend to the set of friends of name"""
    self.name = name
    self.friend = friend

def address(self, name):
    """Returns the address of name"""

def friends(self, name, degree):
```

Comment: What have you tried? What can you use? i.e are you expected/allowed to write your own class? or just use lists and dicts and manage somehow?

Comment: Your question needs more detail, but consider that every person in your address book might require a unique ID. You could have a recursive function that searches for people - pass person 1 into it, it then passes each of that person's friends into the same function until you reach a person with no friends OR you set a max degree. You can count how many times you've called the function to get the degree of friendship.

Comment: Yes I am allowed to use classes

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a class which holds a list which contains all the direct friends of that person. Then what you do is you search through the list when finding certain degrees of friends e.g. a friend of degree 2 is any friend which is not the person or any of his direct friends but another person. Continue adding these people into a "used friend" list to make sure you don't double up. 
An example of this would be:

```
class Person:
    #init a friend list somewhere
    def findDegree (self, degree):
        usedFriends = self.friends
        #example var name is friends
        currentList = self.friends
        for i in range(2, degree + 1):
            #get friends from friend list e.g.
            newList = []
            for j in currentList:
                #add friends while making sure not double ups using usedList
                for k in j.friends:
                    if k in usedFriends:
                        continue
                    newList.append(k)
            for j in newList:
                usedFriends.append(j)
            currentList = newList[:]
            #iterate
        return currentList
```

This is just an example to help you start off. Also consider looking up classes on the internet: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html](http://ttps://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)